# Why is state is always null in my redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm building a very simple contacts application to get familiar with React and Redux. Right now I am trying to build the functionality to add a contact. I thought I had the action and reducer set up correctly but currently the state that is getting passed to my reducer is null. I would expect the current list of contacts to be in the state that is passed. If I log the state after the reducer has executed it doesn't even get the one contact that I would expect to be added, it is still empty. Any help is appreciated!

My code is as follows

Action:

```
function addContact(contact) {
  console.log("it gets to the action");
  return {
    type: 'ADD_CONTACT',
    payload: contact
  }
}

export default addContact;
```

AddContacts Reducer:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
  console.log(state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_CONTACT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        contacts: [
          ...state.contacts,
          {
            name: action.payload.name,
            phone: action.payload.phone
          }
        ]
      })
  }
  return state;
}
```

Component that invokes this action:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AddContactButton from './AddContactButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import addContact from '../actions/action_add_contact'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

class AddContactModal extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {firstName: "", phone: ""};
  }

  handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({firstName: event.target.value})
  }

  handlePhoneChange(event) {
    this.setState({phone: event.target.value});
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log($r.store.getState());
    this.props.addContact({"name": this.state.firstName, "phone": this.state.phone});
  }

  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" className="name" placeholder="Contact Name" onChange={(event) => this.handleNameChange(event)}/>
        <input type="text" className="phone" placeholder="Contact Phone" onChange={(event) => this.handlePhoneChange(event)}/>
        <AddContactButton firstName={this.state.firstName} firstName={this.state.phone} onClick={() => this.onClick()}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contacts: state.contacts
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ addContact: addContact }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddContactModal)
```

Store creation:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);
const initialState = {
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "Miguel Camilo",
      "phone": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "phone": "883292300348"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "phone": "8743847638473"
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "phone": "0988765553"
    }
  ],
  "activeContact": null
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers, initialState) }>
   <App />
  </Provider>
, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Contacts reducer that just returns a hard-coded list of contacts to set up the initial state:

```
export default function () {
  return [{
    "name": "Miguel Camilo",
    "phone": "123456789"
  },{
    "name": "Peter",
    "phone": "883292300348"
  },{
    "name": "Jessica",
    "phone": "8743847638473"
  },{
    "name": "Michael",
    "phone": "0988765553"
  }];
}
```

I'm pretty sure my issue is coming from my use of mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps in the component, when I look at the redux state I see it added a collection "addContacts" which I don't think I want? Shouldn't it just take the payload from the action and add this to the "contacts" collection?

Comment: Did you try to debug using devtools? Try to put console.log when you are dispatching action and also try to see if the values are being pass in reducer.

Comment: try `store={ createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleWare()) }`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are missing the dispatch:

```
    function addContact(contact) {
        console.log("it gets to the action");
        dispatch({
           type: 'ADD_CONTACT',
           payload: contact
        });
   }

   export default addContact;
```